# Disabling the horizontal scroll in kendo tab strip ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui

How to disable the horizontal scroll in the kendo tab-strip ASP.NET Core?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more details in order to check your issue accordingly.